# How to serve multiple angular + express.js apps with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, websocket

I have server with NGINX serving express.js (+ socket.io) server and angular app. And both of this apps have dev versions so it's 4 apps served from one nginx config. Until I added socket.io to express app, everything worked with following config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    server {
        listen       4200;
        server_name  localhost;

        # dev version of angular app
        location /dev {
            expires    -1;
            add_header Pragma "no-cache";
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalicate, post-check=0 pre-check=0";
            alias      /home/user/angular_dev_app/frontend/dist/angular_dev_app;
            try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        # dev version of express server
        location /dev/api {
            rewrite          ^\/dev/api(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_redirect   off;
            proxy_pass       http://localhost:9900/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

        # dev version of angular app
        location / {
            expires    -1;
            add_header Pragma "no-cache";
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalicate, post-check=0 pre-check=0";
            root       /home/user/angular_prod_app/frontend/dist/angular_prod_app;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        # prod version of express server
        location /api {
            rewrite          ^\/api(.*)$ $1 break;

            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_redirect   off;
            proxy_pass       http://localhost:9901;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

But after I added socket.io logic to express app it acts very strange.
All connections excluding socket ones are work without any problems. If I run express and angular app without nginx, socket.io requests are also work without any problem. But when I run server from remote server with nginx, it starts to get called only on `on('connecting', ...)` and ignores any emitting from routes handlers.

## BACKEND

### express.js app:

```
const io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.origins("*:*");


io.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.emit("Hello", `Hello, ${socket.handshake.session.passport.user}`); # gets to frontend locally and remotely

    socket.on("sendImage", (image) => {
        console.log(image);
        io.emit("addImage", image);
    });
});

app.use(require("app.routes")(io));
```

### app.routes.js

```
module.exports = io => {
    const router = express.Router();

    router.post(
        "/some-url",
        (req, res, next) => {
              const result = 'something';
              io.emit("sendImage", result); # gets to frontend only locally

              res.status(200).send({ body: [] });
        }
    );

    return router;
};
```

## FRONTEND

### socket.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import * as io from "socket.io-client";
// import { SocketIOClient } from "socket.io-client";

import { ConfigService } from "./config.service";

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
    private socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;
    private wsOriginUrl: string;
    private wsPath: string;

    constructor(private environment: ConfigService) {
        this.wsOriginUrl = this.environment.config.wsOriginUrl;
        this.wsPath = this.environment.config.wsPath;

        this.socket = io(this.wsOriginUrl, {
            path: this.wsPath,
            transports: ["websocket"]
        });
        this.socket.on("connect", () => this.connected());
        // this.socket.on("disconnect", () => this.disconnected());
        this.socket.on("error", (error: string) => {
            console.log(`ERROR: "${error}" (${this.wsOriginUrl})`);
        });
    }

    public connect() {
        this.socket.connect();
    }

    public disconnect() {
        this.socket.disconnect();
    }

    public emit(chanel, message) {
        return new Observable<any>(observer => {
            console.log(`emit to ${chanel}:`, message); // is called for 'addImage' when both are localhost only
            this.socket.emit(chanel, message, function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    observer.next(data.msg);
                } else {
                    observer.error(data.msg);
                }
                observer.complete();
            });
        });
    }

    public on(event_name) {
        // console.log(`listen to ${event_name}:`);
        return new Observable<any>(observer => {
            this.socket.off(event_name);
            this.socket.on(event_name, data => {
                observer.next(data);
            });
        });
    }

    private connected() {
        console.log("Connected"); // is called when both are localhost or angular local + express remote
    }

    private disconnected() {
        console.log("Disconnected");
    }
}
```

### images.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ImagesService {
    private backendApiUrl: string;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private environment: ConfigService,
        private socketService: SocketService
    ) {
        this.backendApiUrl = environment.config.origin;
    }

    public getServerSentImage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.socketService.on("addImage").pipe(
            map(response => {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            })
        );
    }
}
```

### page.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-page",
    templateUrl: "./page.component.html",
    animations: [fadeInOutTransition],
    styleUrls: ["./page.component.scss"]
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private serverSentImageSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

    constructor(
        private imagesService: ImagesService,
    ) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.serverSentImageSubscription = this.imagesService
            .getServerSentImage()
            .subscribe(
                image => {
                    this.addImage(image);
                },
                error => {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.serverSentImageSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    public addImage(image: any) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Is there any problem with my NGINX config? Or I set up server (or client app?) incorrectly?

Comment: Can you add `proxy_http_version 1.1;`

Comment: @RolandStarke added but it doesn't works still :( https://i.gyazo.com/8ba137cbb2b829a8cb6d5edaefe3f7eb.png

Comment: your screenshot shows that you have working websocket connection. your problem is not related to configuration of nginx. Did you restart nginx after the change suggested by @RolandStarke ?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny yes, of course. Do you know what could be the problem cause? I believe that this is connected to nginx since everything is fine locally

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I have found that at point I call `io.emit(...)` at `app.routes` there are no connected users to socket but there is no disconnection happening since I connect to it

Comment: I wonder whether io.emit() is a problem... Try io.sockets.emit()

Comment: An other option would be a race condition. I I agree the screenshot looks like the connection is fine, so I guess some added delay and therefore other execution order could cause a problem.

Comment: You are sending an image blob? Maybe try with a simple string first. Could you add the client side code? (Other problems could be: using multible nodejs instances or localhost vs live server (CORS or https restrictions that are not enforced by chrome on localhost, etc.))

Comment: @RolandStarke nope, it's just an JSON string like `{ name: 'image.jpg', path: 'path/to/image.jpg' }`

Comment: @RolandStarke I will update question with angular code in ~20-30 minutes

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny sorry, missed you comment. I tried `io.sockets.emit(...)` before but also doesn't work since there are no connected users at all. I think that users get disconnected at some moment but I don't know how to investigate it